# Can Multiple Google Accounts for Google Adwords effect campaign performance

Tags: google, google-ads

I'm managing multiple Google Adwords accounts with different google accounts for each one and each of these separate google accounts has the exact same personal info such as name, sex, date of birth and mobile phone.  Could this somehow be a hinderance to each campaign's performance, because when run them all at the same time the results are flat verses when I run each one by itself?  Could somehow Google see this as the same advertiser and effect the outcome?

Comment: When I was running large SEM campaigns Google had a limit of about 1 million keywords in an account.   Because of this limit we had to have multiple accounts to bid on many millions of keywords.   We had to bid on separated keywords to separate landing pages in different accounts.   If we tried to bid on the same keywords or have the same AdGroup in two different accounts, it caused problems.  Its been several years though, so I'm not sure what the status is at this point.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using each account to advertise for a separate website AND you are bidding on separate keywords within each of your aforementioned accounts - there will be no problem, no effect on performance... that is,  other than inefficiency created due to your decision not to use the tool google created for this very reason: MCC or My Client Center - which gives you a dashboard of all of your AdWords accounts, and allows you to seamlessly move between each one, allowing you to make changes on the fly.

Sign up for your MCC here: https://adwords.google.com/home/tools/manager-accounts/